# kendo grid not binding data correctly

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a mvc application with a kendo Grid

Here's the view code

```
@using Domain.Agromilieu2.Wui.Resources.Bedrijfsgegevens.Views
@using Domain.Agromilieu2.Wui.Models.BeheerTeksten
@model TekstenViewModel.Main
@{
    Layout = WebCore.Views.Layouts.Extended;
}

<h2>Teksten</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("alertWindow")
    .Title("Status Message from Server")
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(400)
    .Height(200)
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
)

@Html.WebCore().Popup.CustomButtons("popupDemo", "Waarde", Html.Kendo().Editor().Name("waardeEditor").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "editorStyle" }).Tools(tools => tools
    .Clear()
    .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough()
    .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
    .InsertUnorderedList().InsertOrderedList()
    .Outdent().Indent()
    .CreateLink().Unlink()
    .InsertImage()
    .SubScript()
    .SuperScript()
    .TableEditing()
    .ViewHtml()
    .Formatting()
    .FontName()
    .FontSize()
    .FontColor().BackColor()        
).ToHtmlString(), new[]{new PopupButton("popupDemoAnnuleren", "Cancel", false),new PopupButton("popupDemoOk", "OK")})

<div class="infoPanel">
    <div id='divSousMenu'>
        <div>
            <h2 class="zoekCriteria">ZOEKCRITERIA</h2>
            <h4 class="resourceSet">Resource Set:</h4>

            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Filter.userName)
            .Name("resourcesSetComboBox")
            .DataTextField("Naam")
            .DataValueField("ID")
            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "comboStyle" })
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceSetsIntoCombo_Read, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name)
                        .Data("onAdditionalData");
                })
                .ServerFiltering(true);
            })
            .AutoBind(false)
            )
        </div>

        <div class='gewijzigdItem'>
            <h4 class="gewijzigdDoor">Gewijzigd door:</h4>  

            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                .Name("usersSetComboBox")
                .DataTextField("DisplayName")
                .DataValueField("UserName")
                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "comboStyle" })
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.GebruikersIntoCombo_Read, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name)
                            .Data("onAdditionalData");
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true);
                })
                .AutoBind(false)    
            )
        </div>

        <div class='vanItem'>
            <h4 class="van">Van:</h4> 
            @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
                .Name("vanTimepicker")
                .Max(DateTime.Today)
                .Events(events => events.Change("onVanTimeChange"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dateTimePickerStyle;" })
            )

        </div>
        <div class='totItem'>
            <h4 class="tot">Tot:</h4>
            @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
                .Name("totTimepicker")
                .Max(DateTime.Today)
                .Events(events => events.Change("onTotTimeChange"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dateTimePickerStyle;" })
            )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="separator"></div>

@*<hr />*@
<div class="zoekResultatLine">
    <h2 class="zoekResultat">ZOEKRESULTAAT</h2> 
</div>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TekstenViewModel.Tekst>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'/>").Width(10).Hidden(!Model.Administrator);

        columns.Bound(product => product.RESOURCE_SET_NAAM).Width(125).ClientTemplate("#= RESOURCE_SET_NAAM#");

        columns.Bound(product => product.Naam).Width(125).ClientTemplate("#= Naam#");

        columns.Bound(product => product.Waarde).Width(125).ClientTemplate("<div id='editorDiv'><div class='input'>#=Waarde#</div><div class='editor'>" +
            Html.WebCore().LinkButton(type: ButtonType.MeerActies, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "openPopupDemo('#: Waarde #', '#: ID #', 'Waarde')" }));

        columns.Bound(product => product.Opmerking).Width(250).ClientTemplate("<div id='editorDiv'><div class='input'>#=Opmerking#</div><div class='editor'>" +
            Html.WebCore().LinkButton(type: ButtonType.MeerActies, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "openPopupDemo('#: Opmerking #', '#: ID #', 'Opmerking')" }));

        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<div id='deleteDiv'><div class='delete'><a class=\"delete iconBtn\" onclick=\"deleteResourceItem(#: ID #, '#: Naam #')\"></a></div></div>").Width(10).Hidden(!Model.Administrator);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Events(events => events.Edit("onCellEdit").DataBinding("onDataBinding"))
    .Groupable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(product => product.ID);
            model.Field(product => product.Naam).Editable(Model.Administrator);
            model.Field(product => product.Opmerking).Editable(Model.Administrator);
            model.Field(product => product.Waarde).Editable(!Model.ReadOnly);
            model.Field(product => product.RESOURCE_SET_ID).DefaultValue(Model.SetID);
            model.Field(product => product.Type).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Objects.Entities.Resources.ResourceType.GLOBAL_RESOURCES);
            model.Field(product => product.Taal).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Agromilieu2Constants.Resources.DEFAULT_TAAL_CODE);
        })
         .Create(create => create.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Create, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
        .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Read, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name, new { setID = Model.SetID }).Data("onReadAdditionalData"))
        .Update(update => update.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Update, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Delete, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
    )
)

@Html.WebCore().Popup.Remove("confirmResourceItemPopup", "Verwijderen resource item", "")

@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render(Links.Bundles.Scripts.BeheerTeksten.Teksten)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onCellEdit(e) {
            var grid      = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var row       = $(e.container).closest("tr");
            var colIdx    = $("td", row).index($(e.container));
            var columname = e.sender.columns[colIdx].field;

            e.container.find("[name='" + columname + "']").toggleClass('editInput');
        }

        function onDataBinding(e) {
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");

            if ($("#resourcesSetComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value() == "")
                grid.showColumn(1);
            else
                grid.hideColumn(1);         
        }

        function onVanTimeChange() {
            var vanTimeValue = kendo.toString($("#vanTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff")
            $("#totTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").min(vanTimeValue);
        }

        function onTotTimeChange() {
            var totTimeValue = kendo.toString($("#totTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff")
            $("#vanTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").max(totTimeValue);
        }

        function onAdditionalData() {
            var code = window.location.pathname.split('/');

            return {
                toepassingsCode: code[5]
            };
        }

        function onReadAdditionalData() {
            var resourceID = $.urlParam('setID');
            if (resourceID) {
                $("#resourcesSetComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value(resourceID);
                $("#resourcesSetComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").enable(false);
            }
            else
                resourceID = $("#resourcesSetComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value();

            var user = $.urlParam('userName');
            if (user) {
                $("#usersSetComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value(user);
                $("#usersSetComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").enable(false);
            }
            else
                user = $("#usersSetComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value();

            var vanTimeValue = $.urlParam('vanTime');
            if (vanTimeValue) {
                $("#vanTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(new Date(Date.parse(vanTimeValue, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")));
                $("#vanTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").enable(false);
            }
            else
                var vanTimeValue = kendo.toString($("#vanTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff")

            var totTimeValue = $.urlParam('totTime');
            if (totTimeValue) {

                $("#totTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(totTimeValue);
                $("#totTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").enable(false);
            }
            else
                var totTimeValue = kendo.toString($("#totTimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff")

            return {
                setID: resourceID,
                userName: user,
                vanTime: vanTimeValue,
                totTime: totTimeValue
            };
        }

        $.urlParam = function (name) {
            var enc = decodeURI(window.location.href);

            var results = new RegExp('[\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(enc);

            if (results != null)
                return results[1];
        }

        function deleteResourceItem(resourceItemID, resourceItemName) {
            domain.Agromilieu2.Wui.BeheerTeksten.Teksten.deleteResourceItem(resourceItemID, resourceItemName);
        }

        var selectedGridRowID = 0;
        var selectedGridColumnName;
        function openPopupDemo(gridCellContent, gridIdentifier, columnIdentifier) {
            var editor = $("#waardeEditor").data("kendoEditor")

            if (('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ReadOnly))' == "false" && '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Administrator))' == "false" && columnIdentifier != "Waarde") || '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ReadOnly))' == "true")
                editor.body.contentEditable = false;
            else                 
                editor.body.contentEditable = true;

            editor.value(htmlDecode(gridCellContent));
            domain.WebCore.popup.show("popupDemo");
            selectedGridRowID      = gridIdentifier;
            selectedGridColumnName = columnIdentifier;
        };

        function htmlDecode(value) {
            return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
        }

        function htmlEncode(value) {
            return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
        }

        function htmlEscape(str) {
            return String(str)
                .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')            
        }

        domain.WebCore.popup.configure("popupDemo")
        .click(function (b) {
            var grid   = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var editor = $("#waardeEditor").data("kendoEditor")

            var parentItem = grid.dataSource.get(selectedGridRowID);

            parentItem.set(selectedGridColumnName, htmlEscape(htmlEncode(editor.value())));
        });

        function showAlertWindow(message) {
            var alertWindow = $('#alertWindow').data('kendoWindow');
            alertWindow.content(message);
            alertWindow.refresh();
            alertWindow.center();
            alertWindow.open();
        }

        function error_handler(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var message = "";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += this + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
                showAlertWindow(message);
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            domain.Agromilieu2.Wui.BeheerTeksten.Teksten.init(
            {
                deleteResourceItemUrl: "@Url.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ResourceItems_Delete())",
                deleteResourceItemMessage: "<p>Bent u zeker dat u '{0}' wil verwijderen?</p><p><strong>Opgelet!</strong><br>Hierbij worden ook alle teksten verbonden aan deze resource set verwijderd.</p>",

                ResourceItems_ReadUrl: "@Url.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ResourceItems_Read())"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

And here's my controller's code.

```
// GET /Agromilieu2/Beheer/Teksten/Teksten
        [HttpGet]
        [Domain.BasisArchitectuur.Framework.MVC.ActionFilters.MenuItem("Teksten")]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenRaadpleger)]
        public virtual ActionResult Teksten(string toepassingsCode = null, long? setID = null, string taalCode = null, string resourceType = null, string user = null)
        {
            bool admin = SecurityHelper.IsActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenAdmin);

            LayoutService.SubTitle = DetailResources.TITEL_Header;

            if (admin)
            { 
                LayoutService.SubmitActions = new List<LinkButton>
                {
                    new LinkButton { ButtonType = ButtonType.Toevoegen, CssClass = "myToevoegenButton", IsDisabled = setID == null, ClientId = "teste" },
                    new LinkButton { ButtonType = ButtonType.Delete, CssClass = "myVerwijderenButton" },
                    new LinkButton { ButtonType = ButtonType.Zoeken, CssClass = "primair myZoekenButton" }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                LayoutService.SubmitActions = new List<LinkButton>
                {
                    new LinkButton { ButtonType = ButtonType.Zoeken, CssClass = "primair myZoekenButton" }
                };
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toepassingsCode))
            {
                return RedirectToAction(MVC.BeheerTeksten.Toepassingen());
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceType) && resourceType == ResourceType.REFE_RESOURCES)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(MVC.BeheerTeksten.RefeTeksten(toepassingsCode, setID, taalCode));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(taalCode))
                    {
                        taalCode = Agromilieu2Constants.Resources.DEFAULT_TAAL_CODE;
                    }
                    LayoutService.SubTitle = string.Format("Beheer Teksten - {0}",
                        BL.Resources.Resources.GetToepassingen().First(x => x.Code == toepassingsCode).Omschrijving);
                    TekstenViewModel.Main model = new TekstenViewModel.Main
                    {
                        DefaultTaal = Agromilieu2Constants.Resources.DEFAULT_TAAL_CODE,
                        Filter = new TekstenViewModel.ZoekCriteria
                        {
                            ResourceSet_ID = setID,
                            Taal           = taalCode,
                            userName       = user 
                        },
                        ToepassingsCode = toepassingsCode,
                        SetID           = setID,
                        ReadOnly        = !(SecurityHelper.IsActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenAdmin) || SecurityHelper.IsActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenBeheer)),
                        Administrator   = SecurityHelper.IsActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenAdmin)

                    };

                    return View(model);
                }
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Domain.BasisArchitectuur.Framework.MVC.ActionFilters.MenuItem("Teksten")]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenRaadpleger)]
        public virtual ActionResult ResourceItems_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, long? setID, string userName, string vanTime, string totTime, string taalCode = Agromilieu2Constants.Resources.DEFAULT_TAAL_CODE)
        {
            DateTime? newVanTime = null;
            DateTime? newTotTime = null;

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vanTime))
                newVanTime = DateTime.Parse(vanTime);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(totTime))
                newTotTime = DateTime.Parse(totTime);

            TekstenViewModel.ZoekCriteria searchCriteria = new TekstenViewModel.ZoekCriteria
                {
                    ResourceSet_ID = setID,
                    type_Code      = ResourceType.GLOBAL_RESOURCES,
                    Taal           = taalCode,      
                    userName       = userName,
                    vanTime        = newVanTime,
                    totTime        = newTotTime
                };

            List<TekstenViewModel.Tekst> resourceItemsList = new List<Models.BeheerTeksten.TekstenViewModel.Tekst>();

            resourceItemsList = GetResourceItemsList(searchCriteria);

            return Json(resourceItemsList.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [Domain.BasisArchitectuur.Framework.MVC.ActionFilters.MenuItem("Teksten")]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenBeheren)]
        public virtual ActionResult ResourceItems_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<TekstenViewModel.Tekst> resourceItems)
        {
            List<ResourceItemDto> entities = new List<ResourceItemDto>();            

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IProxy<IResourceService> proxy = _proxyFactory.Create<IResourceService>())
                    {
                        foreach (TekstenViewModel.Tekst tekstenViewModel in resourceItems)
                        {
                            ResourceItemDto resourceItem = new ResourceItemDto
                            {
                                ResourceItem_ID   = tekstenViewModel.ID,
                                ResourceSet_ID    = tekstenViewModel.RESOURCE_SET_ID,
                                Naam              = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tekstenViewModel.Naam),
                                Opmerking         = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tekstenViewModel.Opmerking),
                                Waarde            = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tekstenViewModel.Waarde),
                                Type_Code         = tekstenViewModel.Type,
                                Taal_Code         = tekstenViewModel.Taal,
                                ResourceWaarde_ID = tekstenViewModel.WAARDE_ID
                            };

                            entities.Add(resourceItem);
                        }

                        proxy.Client.CheckIfNameExists(entities);
                        proxy.Client.AddOrUpdateResourceItem(entities.AsEnumerable());
                    }
                }                

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var errMsg = ModelState.Values
                    .Where(x => x.Errors.Count >= 1)
                    .Aggregate("Model State Errors: ", (current, err) => current + err.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errMsg);
            }

            //ModelState.AddModelError("Naam", );

            //resourceItems = GetResourceItemsList(new TekstenViewModel.ZoekCriteria { Taal = resourceItems.FirstOrDefault().Taal, ResourceSet_ID = resourceItems.FirstOrDefault().RESOURCE_SET_ID });

            return Json(entities.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [Domain.BasisArchitectuur.Framework.MVC.ActionFilters.MenuItem("Teksten")]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenBeheren)]
        public virtual ActionResult ResourceItems_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<TekstenViewModel.Tekst> resourceItems)
        {
            List<ResourceItemDto> entities = new List<ResourceItemDto>();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IProxy<IResourceService> proxy = _proxyFactory.Create<IResourceService>())
                    {
                        foreach (TekstenViewModel.Tekst tekstenViewModel in resourceItems)
                        {
                            ResourceItemDto resourceItem = new ResourceItemDto
                            {
                                ResourceItem_ID = tekstenViewModel.ID,
                                ResourceSet_ID = tekstenViewModel.RESOURCE_SET_ID,
                                Naam = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tekstenViewModel.Naam),
                                Opmerking = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tekstenViewModel.Opmerking),
                                Waarde = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tekstenViewModel.Waarde),
                                Type_Code = tekstenViewModel.Type,
                                Taal_Code = tekstenViewModel.Taal,
                                ResourceWaarde_ID = tekstenViewModel.WAARDE_ID
                            };

                            entities.Add(resourceItem);
                        }

                        proxy.Client.AddOrUpdateResourceItem(entities.AsEnumerable());
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var errMsg = ModelState.Values
                    .Where(x => x.Errors.Count >= 1)
                    .Aggregate("Model State Errors: ", (current, err) => current + err.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errMsg);
            }

            return Json(resourceItems.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }  

        [HttpDelete]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenBeheren)]
        public virtual ActionResult ResourceItems_Delete(long? id)
        {
            using (IProxy<IResourceService> proxy = _proxyFactory.Create<IResourceService>())
            {
                proxy.Client.DeleteResourceItemRecursively(id);
            }

            return Content(CoreService.LastMainScreenUrl ?? MvcConfig.DefaultStartupUrl);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenBeheren)]
        public virtual ActionResult ResourceItems_Delete( [Bind(Prefix="models")] List<TekstenViewModel.Tekst> resourceItems)
        {
            using (IProxy<IResourceService> proxy = _proxyFactory.Create<IResourceService>())
            {
                foreach(TekstenViewModel.Tekst resourceItem in resourceItems )
                {
                    proxy.Client.DeleteResourceItemRecursively(resourceItem.ID);
                }
            }

            return Content(CoreService.LastMainScreenUrl ?? MvcConfig.DefaultStartupUrl);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenRaadpleger)]
        public virtual JsonResult ResourceSetsIntoCombo_Read(string toepassingsCode)
        {
            ResourceWcfDataServiceProxy proxy = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ResourceWcfDataServiceProxy>();

            IEnumerable<ResourceSetsViewModel.ResourceSet> sets =
                Enumerable.Repeat(new ResourceSetsViewModel.ResourceSet { Naam = "Maak een selectie" }, 1).Union(proxy.ResourceSetSet
                 .Where(s => s.ToepassingsCode == toepassingsCode)
                 .Select(s => new
                 {
                     ID        = s.ID,
                     Naam      = s.Naam,
                     Opmerking = s.Opmerking,
                     Type      = s.Type.Code
                 }).ToList()
                 .Select(s => new ResourceSetsViewModel.ResourceSet
                 {
                     ID        = s.ID,
                     Naam      = s.Naam,
                     Opmerking = s.Opmerking,
                     Type      = s.Type
                 }));

            return Json(sets.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [IsAgromilieuActieAllowed(ActieClaims.TekstenRaadpleger)]
        public virtual JsonResult GebruikersIntoCombo_Read(string toepassingsCode)
        {
            IEnumerable<TekstenViewModel.UserInfo> journalingUsers;

            using (IProxy<IResourceService> proxy = _proxyFactory.Create<IResourceService>())
            {
                journalingUsers = Enumerable.Repeat(new TekstenViewModel.UserInfo { UserName = null, DisplayName = "Maak een selectie" }, 1)
                    .Union(proxy.Client.GetUsers(toepassingsCode).Select(x => new TekstenViewModel.UserInfo { UserName = x, DisplayName = x })); 
            }

            return Json(journalingUsers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When I update, read or delete, everything works fine. When I create, it's like I'm not getting back the right data in the grid.

I mean, I create a new record and press Save, it calls the savechanges event of the grid. So far so good, but if I press Save again, it calls the savechanges event again and I get this error.

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

Here's a picture of the grid before creating a new record.

[image]

Here's a picture of the grid after inserting a new record

[image]

The first record should be the last. Have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: You need to change the id for the newly created record. If you leave it as the auto generated id then the grid thinks that this record is required for saving again and will try and push that data back into the create method.

Comment: Ok, sounds logical. How do I do that??

Comment: when saving the new object to the database just give it a new id (if it is an auto generated id then just bind that id back to the model you are sending back) this way the gid knows it is no longer a newly created object.